# Настройки IP адресов сбрасываются через несколько секунд после применения (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ip, маршрутизация

Мне нужно создать локальную сеть со статической маршрутизацией. У меня есть два компьютера (виртуалки, обе Ubuntu 14.04, чистые, только поставленные). Я задаю адреса для них так:

```
vm1:
ip link set eth0 up
ip a add 5.9.30.10/24 dev eth0

vm2:
ip link set eth0 up
ip a add 5.9.30.20/24 dev eth0
```

Сначала все ок, компы пингуются друг с друга, адреса привязаны к интерфейсам:

```
> ip a
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfio_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:FF:47:2c bed FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
    inet 5.9.30.10/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feff:472c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Но через 20-30 секунд все, что я настроила, сбрасывается само по себе:

```
> ip a
...
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfio_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:FF:47:2c bed FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feff:472c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Почему это происходит и как это можно починить?

Comment: да, вам надо сделать глобальный выбор: то ли рулить сетью вручную (как вы попытались сделать), то ли доверить это какому-нибудь «сетевому менеджеру» (чаще всего для этого используется network-manager).

Comment: Или interfaces - удобнее для сервера

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автоподключение к сети через network-manager. Он очищает конфигурацию сети если не может настьроиться. Отключите его

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

или настройте

```
sudo nmtui
```

Comment: вроде как административных полномочий для работы nmtui/nmcli не требуется.

Comment: Смотря как соединение было сделанно... Иногда требуется

Comment: Мне нужно было настроить все вручную в экспериментально-учебных целях, так что отключение nm - то, что было нужно, спасибо. Я просто вырубила его через service